# Quantiles based on raw data or density

Tags: density-function, quantiles, ggplot2

I've created violin plots of my data and included quantile lines. These were created with the `geom_violin` function from `ggplot2` in R. However, I realized that these quantiles differed from the ones I get when I calculate them myself with the `quantile` function. After some investigation I found out that `geom_violin` seems to determine quantiles based on density rather than the raw data ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033341/differing-quantiles-boxplot-vs-violinplot)). So my question is, why generate quantiles in this way rather than based on the raw data? Are there times when one method is preferable to the other?